# Costs for colored figures in Chemistry - A European Journal

Tags: publications, chemistry

I am planning to submit a Chemistry - A European Journal "full paper" article. However, it contains many colored figures. The FAQ does not really answer the question if colored figures will lead to additional costs. Also, I have no idea of what costs to expect, i.e. 20 Euro, 1500 Euro? How is the situation in other journals?

Comment: Rather than finding out the situation in other journals, would it not make more sense to contact the journal you're actually intending to submit to, and ask them for an estimate (if not exact figure)?

Comment: That was my thought.  Why come here, instead of just contacting the journal?  I'm not sure what the SE community could add.

Comment: @JeffL. I just thought that other people might come up with the same question, as really, the FAQ of chemistry a european journal isnt really that informative as it does not really state *how expensive* coloured figures will be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can only be answered by the journal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [author guidelines](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1521-3765/homepage/2111_guideline.html) report:

> The publication of graphical material in color is expensive, and we
>   request that part of the additional costs be carried by the author. As
>   a result of the production process, the online and print versions of
>   the manuscript must be identical. **If color is deemed essential for the
>   scientific understanding and the author does not have access to funds
>   for publication costs, the journal may consider covering the
>   additional costs.**

It seems that unlike many other journals, for what concerns colour figures, this one publishes a printed version which equals the online one. Note, however, the bold part.

An alternative possibility, which is less expensive, would be that of producing the manuscript with all black and white pictures and then delivering the coloured ones as online supplementary material. In fact, from the author guidelines,

> Color and animated multimedia applications are welcome and published
>   online at no cost to the author or reader. Please refer to such
>   applications in the article itself where appropriate (see the
>   Supporting Information).

They might accept pictures too.

In any case, before making any decision, I'd suggest to contact the editor or the journal publishing services.